# How can I make this code shorter with a method

Tags: python, list, if-statement, methods, reverse

```py
#Exercise 9: Check Palindrome Number

#Numbers stored in x/y

x = 121
y = 125

#Transferred int in list

num_y = list(str(y))
num_x = list(str(x))

#Flipping the list

rev_y = num_y[::-1]
rev_x = num_x[::-1]

#Compare the flip if they are palindrome

if num_y == rev_y:
    print("Yes. given number is palindrome number")
else:
    print("No. given number is not palindrome number")

if num_x == rev_x:
    print("Yes. given number is palindrome number")
else:
    print("No. given number is not palindrome number")
```

Comment: Do you know how to define a function in general, or just not how to define this particular function?

Comment: This is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. What actually do you find difficult about the problem? Did you make any attempt to solve the problem yourself? If you did, what went wrong, and what *specific* question do you have about fixing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Define a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) using `def`.
No need to change the integer argument converted to string into a list. Just operate with the string - it supports [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/967621)
to reverse the string.
Return `True` or `False` from the function depending on whether the string is the same as the reverse string.

```
def is_palindrome(n):
    s = str(n)
    return s == s[::-1]

x = 121
print(is_palindrome(x))
# True

y = 125
print(is_palindrome(y))
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function.

```py
def print_if_number_is_palindrom(number):
    if str(number) == str(number)[::-1]:
       print("Yes, given number is palindrome number")
    else:
       print("No, given number is not palindrome number")

x = 121
y = 125
print_if_number_is_palindrom(x)
print_if_number_is_palindrom(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

##### The Goal:

- Clean up code
- Move the main logic to a function

##### Approach:

- Create generalized function which can be used for any type of palindrome
- Pass numbers into function as string

##### Result

```
def is_palindrome(term):
    for i in range(len(term)):
        if term[i] != term[(len(term)-i-1)]:
            return False
    return True
```

```
num_x = str(121)
print('num_x palendrome?',is_palindrome(num_x))
```

output -> 'num_x palindrome? True'

```
num_y = str(122)
print('num_y palendrome?',is_palindrome(num_y))
```

output -> 'num_x palindrome? False'

##### Note:

Technically [a method is a function defined within a class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#:%7E:text=A%20method%20is%20a%20function,%2C%20sort%2C%20and%20so%20on.).
As such what you are actually asking for is this:

```
class ClassExample():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.string = ''
        
    def is_palindrome(self,term):
        for i in range(len(term)):
            if term[i] != term[(len(term)-i-1)]:
                return False
        return True
    
ex = ClassExample()
```

**Test:**

```
ex.is_palindrome('121')
```

Answer (score 0):

here is Sorter method:

```
num = '1421'
if num == str(num)[::-1]:
    print('The given number is PALINDROME')
else:
    print('The given number is NOT a palindrome')
```

output:

```
The given number is NOT a palindrome
```

This will help you.

Comment: In your example num is already a string. No need for a cast.